# Why won't my AT Command read SMS messages?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm attempting to write a program which would enable texts to be sent out to customers, I'm using AT Commands with a GSM modem to accomplish this, I have looked at various bits of Documentation but have been unable to find a solution for the following problem.

I am attempting to make the GSM modem return all of the text messages contained within its memory, I have tried many combinations of AT Commands and Parsing techniques to throw this into a text box, but to no avail.

Any help on this would be most appreciated, my code is below

```
 private SerialPort _serialPort2 = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200);
        private void MailBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _serialPort2.Open();

            //_serialPort2.Write("AT+CMGF=1 \r");
            _serialPort2.Write("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"");

            string SerialData = _serialPort2.ReadExisting();

            var getnumbers = new string((from s in SerialData where char.IsDigit(s) select s).ToArray());
            var getText = SerialData;
            SendTxt.Text = getnumbers;
            SendMsgBox.Text = getText;

            //for (int i = 0; i < SerialData.Length; i++ )
            //{
            //    if (char.IsDigit(SerialData))
            //}
            //.Text = _serialPort2.ReadExisting();

            //string[] text = { textBox1.Text };

            //IEnumerable<string> formattext = from words in text where words.("+447") select words;
            // foreach (var word in formattext)
            //{
            //SenderBox.Items.Add(word.ToString());

            // }

            _serialPort2.Close();
            //_serialPort2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort2_DataReceived);


        }
```

Comment: Try sending the string "AT" and see if you get "OK" back. This way you can determine whether the communication between modem and PC works as expected.

Comment: The word "OK" comes back no problem, and I can read all the SMS messages using HyperTerminal, but for some reason it only shows the actual AT command in the Text Box